# How can I access an IAP protected resource using Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-iap

How can I access an IAP protected resource using Python? More specifically I'd like to generate the `Bearer` token needed in the `Authorization` header to make calls to the IAP protected resource.

I have created a service account, given it "IAP-Secured Webapp User" permissions and have downloaded its JSON credentials to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have created a service account for authentication, you can use an OIDC token for authentication into IAP-secured resources.

The steps to obtain and use the token for authentication are shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap-make-request-python), but here is a little summary:

- Head to the Cloud IAP page in the console and edit the OAuth client of the resource you wish to access to.
- With the client ID you get from the Credentials page, request an [OIDC](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) token.
- Include the OIDC token in the `Authorization: Bearer` header, and that way you will have an authenticated request to the IAP-protected resource.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. Could you provide me with a Python code sample? I've tried getting this to work myself but failed.

Comment: There are some samples available in this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/iap), and clone this repository into your local machine:

`git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples.git`. 

Go to the `iap` directory and follow the instructions indicated in the link above.

If you want a more specific code, you can try [this one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iap/make_iap_request.py)

Comment: I've had a look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iap/make_iap_request.py previously. In my case I have a downloaded JSON credentials. You don't happen to know which changes I need to make to make https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iap/make_iap_request.py work with the JSON file? The API is rather messy for a beginner...

Comment: Please see https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/a3cc32c80c3594844009c55ff9233591/revisions. Let me know if you have any input.

Comment: Since you are using JSON credentials, I understand that you require a JSON web token (JWT). In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto#securing_iap_headers) you can find all the steps for securing your app. Be aware this is valid for apps in a flexible environment. For a standard environment, you will have to use the approach indicated [here] (https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto#get_identity_gae), which involves using the [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#users).

Comment: What if I need to use an user account instead of a SA ?